# Remove file extension from file within dir

Tags: python-2.7

I am wanting to remove any given file name extension from a directory specific path only with Python 2.7.3. os.path.splitext returns the extension if you specify the actual file from onset. But I am wanting to throw the script a directory and use os.list.dir to go through the directory. I could not find either how to actually remove the file name extension. Say if it returned 'foo.png' how am I able to remove the ".png" extension permanently? I thought os.remove(file_name_extension) might help but it doesn't seem to in this instance

This is what I have so far as far as testing goes.

```
def main():
   folder_path = sys.argv[1] 
   for file in os.listdir(folder_path):
      current = os.path.join(folder_path, file) 

   print "\n\t%s" % file
```

So this is working fine to print to screen the files and their extensions in the directory specified. 
How am I able to then manipulate the file's extension to remove it permanently?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the result I wanted with some code below that did the 
job for my private project. While it may be horrible it does exactly what it
was intended to do from onset in a roundabout way.

```
if extension == ".png":

    folder_path_length = len(folder_path)+1
    extension = len(file)-4 + folder_path_length
    filename = file[:extension]

    os.rename(current, current[:extension])

    extension = len(file)-4 
    truncated_filename = file[:extension]

    print "\n\t%s \n\tnow renamed to: %s" % (filename, truncated_filename)

    files_renamed_count +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the path and name of the file without the extension, then you can simply use `os.path.splitext(current)[0]` to turn e.g. `path/to/foobar.txt` into `path/to/foobar`. If you simply want the name and not the full path (without the extension), you can use `os.path.basename`:

```
os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(current))[0]
```

to turn `path/to/foobar.txt` into just `foobar`.